# Modern Warfare 3 crashes my computer in the middle of game

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

This might be a really specific question, but I've searched online and found many solutions that don't work, so this is sort of my last resort before formatting my computer. This is my setup:

- Graphics card: EVGA SuperClocked GeForce GTX 570 HD (Running dual
  monitors)
- Memory: 8GB GSKILL Ripjaws X Series
- CPU: i5 2500k OC'd to 4.5
- MOBO: ASRock P67 EXTREME4

The game crashes **only** under 3 separate circumstances:

1. When I finish a match in multiplayer
2. When I finish a mission in single player
3. When I get on an AC-130 (be it single player or multiplayer)

And I'm running it in max settings. The really annoying thing that makes it hard to test is that it doesn't happen every time (AC130 does, but unfortunately I don't get it every time).

And by crash I mean fully crash, it doesn't send me to the desktop, both screens go blank and I have to turn off and back on the computer.

Any suggestion is extremely welcome, even if it's just a way to reproduce the problem every time would help me a lot for testing purposes.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I started a bounty. More details about the crash:

- It usually happens on explosions (cars, concussive, AC130 big gun) but it's not limited to that, sometimes it happens out of nowhere, other times when game starts or ends.
- I tried without overclocking and it didn't work
- I tried it with the game's "Safe Mode" and it crashed too (not that safe I guess)
- Updated my mother board's audio drivers and have latest video card drivers
- Crash happens roughly once every hour
- Screen goes blank and I can still hear half a second of the last sound in the game being repeated over and over (an exaggerated example of this is if the guy said "Target down" I will hear "down,down,down,down,down,down" until I restart my computer, without exagerating I would probably hear "n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n")
- Video card fan speeds up like crazy and gets really noisy
- The temperature of my video card is usually around 80 degrees, but that's with every game so I don't think heating is the problem
- I have two monitors. I disabled on of them and it didn't fix the problem
- I turned off antialiasing and some other effects in the advanced video settings, and I still go the crash
- Erased MW3, re-downloaded and re-installed it, and it crashed on the first game I tried
- Took out my CPU overclocking and it still crashed
- Video card is overclocked by manufacturer [see here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130620)
- Crash is not logged in the Windows' Event Viewer
- I'm not 100% sure, but I sort of remember the problem started after some Windows update, after that Windows update Skype also started acting up (as soon as I picked up a phone call, Skype would crash, I had to download the next version's beta to get rid of that problem)
- Steam overlay is disabled, and it still crashes

I'll post more details as I remember them.

Also these are some of the games I usually play or have played, and I have had no problems with them:

- Starcraft 2
- Skyrim
- Call of Duty 4
- Call of Duty MW2
- Borderlands
- Left 4 Dead 2
- Payday
- The Witcher 2
- Civilization V
- Batman Arkam Asylum (Although this one drops frame rate drastically only on boss battles, weird too. It doesn't crash though)
- Counter Strike Source
- Portal
- Portal 2
- Half-Life 2
- Deus Ex Human Revolution
- Among others

Thanks!

More news:

By **changing the game's sound from "Windows Default" to "Stereo"** I was able to reduce the occurrence of this problem to once every 3 to 5 hours, however, the problem persists. If is a clue to anyone, your advice is really appreciated. Thanks.

It just crashed again a few minutes ago according to the log, at 8:05pm and this is the only info I get in the event viewer:

[image]

The ones above it say (from bottom to top):

- Unable to produce a minidump file from the full dump file.
- The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x00000116 (0xfffffa800addb4e0, 0xfffff8800fa0afa4, 0xffffffffc000009a, 0x0000000000000004). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: .
- (Critical)The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
- Audit events have been dropped by the transport.  0

**EDIT:**

So the bounty is about to end, and I didn't get any conclusive solution. I will keep trying to fix this, and will post my solution once I'm find the solution. I hope this helps anyone have the same problem.

Thanks for everyone's time, you guys have been really helpful, I will let you all know when this is fixed.

**EDIT - FINAL UPDATE**

It was a strange form overheating. I call it strange because it crashes soon after it gets to 80 degrees, but I've played other games (Startcraft 2 for example) at around 86 degrees without problems, which is why I disregarded this possibility right away. Lately I've been setting the GPU fan to spin as fast as it can using MSI Afterburner, and I haven't had any crash since. I was able to set back the audio to Dolby 5.1, put back the steam overlay and everything. So I can happily play now.

Thanks everyone for all your help, I learned a lot from this experience, and although the problem and solution were somewhat simple (except for the fact that other games run all right when the GPU is warmer) I hope it helps others having any issue addressed here.

Thanks again and happy gaming.

Comment: Have you had a look in Windows Event Viewer to see if there's anything in there? On Win 7 go into your start menu and type in the box at the bottom "eventvwr" click this, expand Windows Log tab, then go through "Application" and "System". See if there is anything at the exact time of the crash which could provide some information?

Comment: @IttyBrittyGirlGamer: I actually did, it showed some application which right now I don't remember its name (it was to improve download speeds or something, I never consciously install anything like that), but I removed it and it still crashes. I'll find the name of the app when I get back home. Thanks!

Comment: Have you played any other game since MW3?  Are those games still stable?  Also, is that a custom built machine?

Comment: One last question, is your memory overclocked by any chance?

Comment: @yx. Yeah, I put a list of games I usually play without problems. I can play SC2 for HOURS and my computer will be fine.

Comment: @yx. No, I didn't overclock my memory, just the CPU. The video card is overclocked though, but by the manufacturer.

Comment: If possible, try posting the last error you can find closest to the time of the crash from your event viewer here, it may help.

Comment: @yx. Ah I forgot to put that in the details. I get no error related to this in the event viewer. It only says "System was restored after unexpected restart, possible causes of crash: out of memory, application failed... blah blah" no the exact words, but it doesn't give me a lot of info.

Comment: one last thing to try, what is your sound card (if you have one, pull it out), if not, go into the settings and change the sample rate to a different bit rate at 44.1khz or 48khz

Comment: @yx No sound card, it's integrated to the mobo, I'll give this a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @yx I set the audio to 48khz and I was able to play for two hours straight. Unfortunately I didn't get time to play more, but I'll keep testing today. Thanks!

Comment: Have you done stability tests on the CPU, GPU and the memory? Have you checked whether your power supply provides enough power for all the components in the computer? Does the event log report anything?

Comment: @Tom I have, when I first OC'd I made sure everything was running perfectly. I performed several overnight tests with favorable results. I have a 1000w PSU which provides more wattage than my computer needs (I haven't SLI'd yet). And the event viewer doesn't report anything which is really surprising.

Comment: @yx It just crashed with 48khz, I timed it this time, it 12 minutes. I'm starting to lose hope.

Comment: @Carlos ugh, well that sucks

Comment: I guess its time to stop playing MW3 and play BF3 :P

Comment: @yx hahaha I guess that too =( thanks for all the help man

Comment: @Carlo: Is there a dump available at `C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP`? Could you compress / zip it and see whether you could upload it  so that we can analyze it? In any case, **[`116`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** is a [TDR error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487368). This means that your Graphics Card is trying to reset but doesn't come back again; this can either be by power issues, overheating issues, memory issues or a problem with the card. Strange enough, the sound now looks like just a coincidence.

Comment: @Carlo: Playing on lower settings or a resolution might help. I still find it weird though that *only this game* results in that error. It's not really more heavy than other games, is it? Or perhaps you are using the full graphics memory on this game?

Comment: @TomWijsman I'll try to zip it and put it somewhere later today. The file is 629mb big, so it'll take a while. I will let you know, thank you!

Comment: @TomWijsman I tried playing in lower settings / resolution but no luck =(

Comment: gl with the fix, curious to know what the problem is

Comment: @yx found the problem, see last part of the question for details, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I can't find anyone else with this specific problem, but the general "modern warfare 3 black screen" issues people are encountering seem to be fixed by:

- Updating your graphics drivers.  I think there was a special release for the BF3 beta recently that caused issues with MW3 at launch.  Even if you've updated recently, check for a newer revision.
- [Verify your Steam cache](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335)
- [Disable the Steam overlay](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8882-bmxl-0801#overlay)

Beyond that I'm afraid I don't know - there's so many tiny things that can go terribly wrong with a recent game and an individual PC setup that I'm not sure how to advise you in your current situation.

I note that you're overclocking, if you stop, does that help any?  That's the first thing I try if I'm having an issue of any type while overclocking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried all 3 of those. I already have the latest gtx570 drivers, steam cache is ok according to that steam tool and steam overlay is currently disabled. And yeah you're right, maybe I should try it without overclocking, it hadn't crossed my mind because if OC is unstable it's usually noticeable in every game you play and all the tools I've used to test overclocking are stable, but it's still worth a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried it without the OC, it crashed too... =(

Answer (score 4):

This sounds very similar to an [issue I ran into a while ago](https://superuser.com/questions/91430/constant-crashes-in-windows-7-64bit-when-playing-games)

Even though everything checked out normally, it turns out that somehow my memory has gone bad (despite passing all memtests!).

I eventually figured this out by placing only one stick of memory into my system at a time, and it would constantly crash with one stick but not the other.

Ever since I replaced my memory I've had no problems with my system.

The only other thing I can offer is to check the voltage levels for your memory and other components.  Some motherboards set the default voltage levels to be too low/high for certain types of memory, which can cause them to burn out faster.  (I suspect this is what happened to my machine).

Comment: I can try the memory thing, but if the problem was the voltage, wouldn't it crash too with all the other games I've played?

Comment: @Carlo not necessarily, it depends on how much memory the games use.  GL with your diagnosis, it took me a loooong time and much aggravation to solve my problem.  These kinds are rarely easy to figure out.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll run CPUID to check the voltages next time I play MW3, the good thing is that both monitors freeze, so I'll be able to see the voltage at the exact moment the freeze happens.

Comment: wow, your bad memory passed an overnight run of memtest86??

Comment: @Jeff yup, it was totally unexpected.  Its why I was so sure it couldn't be the memory, it was the last thing I replaced.  I swapped the PSU, Video card, hard drive, even tried reseating my CPU.

Comment: I'll definitely try the memory tonight.

Comment: @Carlo any luck?  curious what the problem is

Comment: I didn't get a lot of time to test. I decided to make it crash again before trying the memory thing. Before starting to play I set my sound from Windows Default to Stereo, and I played for 1.5 hours and no crash... which I thought was weird. I'll play some more right now and if it crashes I'll start testing the memory thing. I'll update tomorrow. Thanks! =)

Comment: It was the sound :S I just played for 3 ~ 4 hours and no crashes...

Comment: I'll play some more hours tomorrow, but it looks very promising

Comment: @Carlo awesome, windows sound can be weird.

Comment: It just crashed again =(, I'm trying the memory thing right now.

Comment: No good, changing the memory sticks didn't work. It still crashed after a few hours of play.

Comment: @Carlo that sucks, well I'm out of ideas, sorry

Comment: No worries, at least it doesn't happen every hour now and I don't usually play for more than 3 (on weekdays at least). Thanks for the help =).

Answer (score 2):

Just to definitively rule out overheating, **I'd open the case and place a large house fan blowing directly on the open side of the PC at full blast.** If you still get the crash in that scenario, then excess heat *cannot* be the reason why.

Beyond that, the standard PC stability troubleshooting rules apply:

Try

- run [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/) overnight and see if your CPU is stable
- run [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) overnight and see if your memory is stable
- run [Furmark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) for an hour or so (be careful as this thing loads GPUs far beyond any realistic load)

Comment: I haven't tried the big fan, but the rest I have when I overclocked my computer. Prime95 ran stable for like 12 hours, I don't remember the exact results of Memtest86 but it also was favorable. I'll try Furmark, it's the only one I don't have. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't notice it was you Jeff :). Thanks for trying to help :).

Comment: there are rumblings of some very obscure sound chipset incompatibilities in some games. If you have access to an externally connected USB sound device (headset, etc) try using that and disabling the on-board sound to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I did try that, I originally thought that was the cause of the crash. I have the Tritons ax720 headset, which has that external usb sound device you mention, I plugged it into the computer and plugged the headset into it, it installed some generic drivers and I used it for a few days, until I thought the crash was caused by that. I haven't used it since, but the crashes remain.

Comment: I would like to add: You can also [test your Video Memory](http://majorgeeks.com/Video_Memory_Stress_Test__d5896.html) in a lot of cases. :)

Comment: @carlo did furmark pass overnight? If you can pass Prime95 overnight, Memtest86 overnight, Furmark overnight.. you're pretty solid.

Comment: I just did like an hour of memtest and it was ok, when I OC'd it passed Prime95 overnight too. I will try furmark tonight. Thanks.

Comment: I just ran Furmark, this is what I got with the 15 min burn-in benchmark http://screencast.com/t/u2UzsFvtZmfQ

Comment: @JeffAtwood I didn't do furmark the whole night. I'll try that tonight, any recommended settings for accurate results?

Comment: @JeffAtwood Hey jeff, it was overheating, it's strange because this game crashes at 80 degrees, but I can play other games at 86 degrees without problems. See the last edit in my question for details. Thanks!

Comment: @Carlo guess you should've done what he suggested :P

Comment: @yx I know I just blindly disregarded it due to the other information I had, but I guess I forgot I was dealing with a computer and computers do whatever the hell they want sometimes lol

Comment: @yx nope, it keeps crashing, it started around 3 days ago, and it keeps doing it really fast, I can't play more than 3 games without a crash... back to square one. I'm going to do SLI in my computer, I hope that somehow helps...

Answer (score 2):

> By changing the game's sound from "Windows Default" to "Stereo" I was able to reduce the occurrence of this problem to once every 3 to 5 hours, however, the problem persists. If is a clue to anyone, your advice is really appreciated. Thanks.

Given that this seems to be *pretty* audio-related; try changing your default audio format to different values, you can find this options in the properties of your sound device:

[image]

The rule of thumb here is to go for *lower settings* as they are less of an impact, so try `24 bit, 44100 Hz` as well as `16 bit, 48000 Hz` and `16 bit, 44100 Hz`. At least try the two values involving `44100 Hz` because these should really be working. It might be that Modern Warfare 3 has problems with your specific audio card driver and its format settings.

Changing the type of sound seems from non-Stereo to Stereo settings already made the impact on the Sound card lower, so changing the format might have additional relieving effects. You might also want to check that all sound effects are disabled on the Enhancements tab and / or that it is set to an immediate mode. Again, to ensure that the load on your audio card is decreased, the latency is low and the buffers don't get fill because there is something slow.

Other than that, trying older more stable drivers might have possitive effects. But I really think you should be looking for audio related issues. Thinking about audio related issues, the [Deferred Procedure Calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Procedure_Call) can interfere with audio so it might be that you have some spikes there. What does the [**DPC Latency Checker**](http://www.thesycon.de/deu/latency_check.shtml) report to you? It might also play a role...

[image]

Comment: Wow, very detailed. I'll check all of this tonight. I've been seriously considering getting a new sound card (the one I currently use is integrated to my MOBO). I suppose it is possible that using another sound card could fix this issue. What do you think?

Comment: @Carlo: Possible, you can either be sure by actually replacing it or running a few stability test as said in Jeff's answer. That's up to you...

Comment: I'll definitely run the tests first. I'll bang my head against the wall if I buy a sound card and the problem is not fixed.

Comment: I get this all the time, not sure what it means http://screencast.com/t/jG7wP8wwMDo

Comment: @Carlo: That means you have a good latency system, there are no drivers or devices that are generating spikes. A spike is a routine that doesn't return within a certain amount of micro seconds. That can result in things like when you play a Full HD video it suddenly stutters each X seconds, some hick-ups in audio; and even in games. But you don't have that in this case so that's not where to look for problems... :)

Comment: Too bad =( every time I which that had been problem to have something to start with, I'm still in the fog

Comment: To be honest, I think this is kind of a waste of time -- he already tried disabling on-board sound and using an external USB sound headset. That should, at least if @carlo did it right, definitively rule out the on-board audio because *it isn't being used*.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think it is not an audio problem. I got one of those USB mini audio devices (a really cheap one), so it's using that instead of the on-board one, and it still crashed after 10 minutes of play. So I'm sort of back to square one.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Ah, seems I haven't read that information. Then indeed most of it won't help much.

Comment: @Carlo: Try Jeff's last suggestion (disabling all the drivers) which should definitely rule out audio. As you got a TDR BSOD, you should be looking more towards your Graphics Card and/or related memory / power issues. Try the VRAM test I mentioned on Jeff's answer, as well as running FurMark over the night.

Comment: @Carlo: Some other suggestions from personal experience: **Enable your page file** if you disabled it and [do step 7 and 8 here](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=113433), this amongst some other fixes (keep an eye on your event log, monitor your CPU/MEM/GPU resources with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), debug the crash dump, refitting memory and GPU) fixed most if not all of [my TDR occurences](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=TDR&user=250&room=118) a while ago. I came from weekly/daily TDR BSODs to monthly/none...

Comment: @carlo playing the game with *no* sound is also a quick way to diagnose (just disable all sound devices in device manager, etc)

Answer (score 1):

This is a mega long shot, but a similar thing used to happen to me whenever I played CSS, about an hour in, with no warning, regardless of graphics settings, the game would freeze and I'd hear the "n-n-n-n-n-n" you described of audio looping.  Brand new computer, first game I installed.  It was the only game that caused this error.

I always thought it was a heat issue as well, but if it's not running higher than other games, than I doubt it is.

I never figured it out until I got into the APB beta, and had the same issue.  I e-mailed their support team and gave all the details I could.  They told me to update my BIOS drivers.  I don't know why it solved the problem but it did, and I haven't had the issue since.

**I would have posted this just as a comment, but I registered just to offer this advice.

Also I noticed you said at the end of games and in AC-130's, the screen goes mostly black and white at these points.  I don't know if that could have something to do with it.  To recreate it, create a private match and get a friend to spawn with tac insertions so you can quickly farm an AC-130?

Comment: That's a good idea, I never thought of constructing my own scenario to reproduce it at will. I love that. A friend told me I should update the BIOS too, but he told me that as a "guess" and not as an experience. Yesterday I mingled some more with the audio based on a suggestion someone gave me here, and I was able to play for 2 hours sans-crash. This will definitely be my next solution attempt. Thank you!

Comment: I tried updating the BIOS yesterday, but I got a lot of warnings "If you do this ASROCK is not responsible for malfunctions blah blah", it said it could make the MOBO stop working, etc. I've never done a BIOS update, so I don't know if that's normal.

Comment: Well I had a dell at the time and I just downloaded the drivers from their website. If you're not sure what you're doing than I wouldn't recommend it.  Can you contact the manufacturer for more information?

Comment: @carlo updating your mobo BIOS is always a good idea. You've tried about everything else so I think this is worth doing.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue very similar with a machine with the GeForce GTX 570ti and after struggling through various suggestions on the EVGA forums, the core of it came down to the annoying way NVIDIA drivers include sound device drivers. An uninstall (you need to fully clear them out) and a selective reinstall of the latest approved 570 drivers sorted out that issue.

Have a look at the [link I followed on the evga forums](http://www.evga.com/forums/tm.aspx?m=586183) on removal of the NVIDIA HD Sound Device

Comment: That's interesting. So how does the selective reinstall go? What do I need to avoid. Can you go in a little more detail, I think this could help since I think the problem is mainly caused by audio.

Comment: I'll find the link and update my answer when I get back to my desktop

Comment: no need to uninstall, just disable any unwanted sound drivers in the sound control devices panel. That's what I do...

Comment: @JeffAtwood ah thanks for the info, I'll give that a shot

Comment: An FYI - I needed to entirely uninstall them,disabling didn't work - the various EVGA threads on it seem to indicate there is just something fundamentally borked with the sound device drivers from Nvidia

Answer (score 0):

You made note of an update to windows and skype that happened about the same time as the problem. try rolling back to before the windows update and then make sure skype is not running in the task manager. and see if the problem keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

no matter what you do its going to happen. there is nothing u can do about it. I am a mw3 survival player and my game crashes at around 150 wave(which usually takes 8-10 hours). Its because the pc is unable to render all the graphics items like sound, explosions, choppers etc. What you can try is go to the settings of the game and reduce the volume to 0% when you get into the scenario where lot of things happening and then bring it back on to whatever suits you...worked for me couple of times. Rest there is no possible solution we as in all the survival players could find.